# PHP Magento 2 REST Integration

Tags: php, magento2

I have this code to integrate Magento 2 REST. This uses Conusmer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Key and Access Token generated from the Integration. The Integration is Activated. However, I am getting all the time homepage as a response.

```
<?php
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);

    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}

// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION
$consumerKey = 'cd1nu5t9ri2e0sssugckups6y821ouga';
$consumerSecret = 'uhkvidkxar29h60wahr5wv28y43ecvdx';
$accessToken = '58y0qm4ketr6iwd5a2q3qs4ov6l1f2j1';
$accessTokenSecret = '1iu2q1aek1q7v1dgtnjyj8ytcmvi7r9c';

$method = 'GET';
$url = 'http://localhost:8082/eam/api/rest/products';

//
$data = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
];

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($result);
```

My Response is like

```
string(28788) "<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head >
    <script>
var require = {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8082/eam/pub/static/version1486025920/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"
};
```

Comment: you $url is wrong, it's supposed  looks like http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1

Comment: Then I get this error- string(47) "{"message":"Request does not match any route."}"

Comment: post your new $url value